# Como corrigir texto sobreposto no cabeçalho com biblioteca MPDF

Tags: php, mpdf

Estou tendo um problema com o cabeçalho em relação ao texto de corpo ao gerar um PDF.

O cabeçalho está sendo sobreescrito pelo texto do corpo, como resolver isso?

Estou usando o método `SetHTMLHeader` para o cabeçalho e o método`WriteHTML` para o texto de corpo. Existe alguma forma de se aumentar o tamanho reservado para o cabeçalho com essa biblioteca, ou alguma outra coisa que resolva?

**Meu código atual:**

```
<?php
session_start();
include('mpdf60/mpdf.php');
$paragrafo = "";
for($x=1;$x<=12;$x++){
    $paragrafo.=$_SESSION['c'.$x]."<br/>";
}
$cabecalho = $_POST['cabecalho'];

$mpdf=new mPDF();
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader($cabecalho);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($paragrafo);
$mpdf->Output();
exit;?>
```

**Como eu queria que ficasse:**

[image: Simulação da saída desejada]

**Como está ficando:**

[image: Saída real, com erro]

Comment: Pode colocar o código aqui?

Comment: @GiancarloAbelGiulian coloquei aqui

Comment: O código que monta o texto é só isso mesmo?

Comment: @DiegoFelipe  coloquei o começo do código agora

Comment: esse é o código completo do arquivo que monta o pdf @DiegoFelipe

Comment: Bom, você não está definindo a posição de impressão na página, apenas está mandando "imprimir" um monte de coisa. Não é a biblioteca que vai adivinhar onde você quer os textos, certo?

Comment: mas onde eu faço isso? nao entendi a documentação dessa biblioteca @Bacco

Comment: @AlexandreMartinsMontebelo não tem nenhum exemplo de como posicionar a informação na documentação? Talvez numa destas respostas tenha algo que possa ser aproveitado (não cheguei a ler, é apenas uma sugestão de pesquisa) http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=mpdf+is%3Aquestion - De qualquer forma, vamos aguardar se alguém posta alguma resposta que ajude. Enquanto isso, se puder, dê uma espiadinha nos exemplos.

Comment: Olhando rapidamente, me parece que ao criar o PDF, você pode especificar as margens da página, mas não sei se isso ajudaria. Em inglês tem umas soluções com CSS, talvez sirva de ponto de partida. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538109/change-top-margin-of-second-page-using-mpdf Outra coisa que talvez solucionasse, seria acrescentar o material do header no corpo da página. Talvez não seja o caminho mais elegante.

Comment: eu tentei essa sua segunda opção primeiramente, de colocar tudo no corpo, só que o texto do cabeçalho ficava muito abaixo do esperado, ficava parecendo parte do corpo mesmo, nem com css resolvia, vou ver se da certo essa primeira solução @Bacco

Comment: Consegui! mudei os parâmetros ao instanciar a classe mpdf

Comment: @AlexandreMartinsMontebelo eu dei uma formatada na sua pergunta, mas já que resolveu, você pode postar a solução como resposta para sua própria pergunta, no campo abaixo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui! Obrigado @Bacco pelo link!
alterei a linha a seguir:

```
$mpdf=new mPDF();
```

por :

```
$mpdf = new mPDF(
             '',    // mode - default ''
             '',    // format - A4, for example, default ''
             0,     // font size - default 0
             '',    // default font family
             15,    // margin_left
             15,    // margin right
             58,     // margin top    -- aumentei aqui para que não ficasse em cima do header
             0,    // margin bottom
             6,     // margin header
             0,     // margin footer
             'L');  // L - landscape, P - portrait
```

Comment: Perfeito! Usei isso também e funcionou...

Comment: Muito bom! Usei aqui e também deu certo. Obrigado!

Comment: Funcionou Perfeitamente!